# useEffect isnt fetching any data from sanity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schema, sanity, groq

i am using sanity with react i made a sanity schema and now i am trying to fetch the data from sanity using react.

projects.jsx

```
export default function Projects() {

  
  const {projects, setProjects} = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "projects"]'

    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data) => setProjects(data))
  }, [])

  console.log(query)


  return (

    <div>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <h1>{project.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
```

my sanity schema.js

```
export default createSchema({
  name: 'default',
 
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    /* Your types here! */
    projects,
  ]),
})
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is the data fetched from the client? You should get state as a destructured array `const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
`

Comment: sorry can yoy please elaborate

Comment: Can you check if you receive data from this line `client.fetch(query).then((data) => console.log(data))`. In investigating it's useful to check it one step at a time. First this, then that - until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `const {projects, setProjects} = useState([])` to `const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])`. You are using the flower brackets instead of square brackets.